# XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, cors, slim

I decided to upload my html5 game to Facebook platform, but I have a problem with the requests to my api/server because now requests come from a different domain (`https://apps.facebook.com/mygame`).

I have received this error:

***XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myurl/api/login. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.***

This is my AJAX request:

```
function login(token)
{

  $.ajax({
     url: 'https://myurl/api/login',
     method: 'get',
     headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token},
     contentType: "application/json",
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
     },                        
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // To next state
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Error
     }
  });
}
```

The requests from my server works, but from facebook it doesn't, this is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

The API is done with slim framework (php) and my server is Apache.
I've tried a lot of options like setting the headers in the `.htaccess` or in the AJAX requests, but I don't achieve it.
How could I do it?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you put the `<IfModule>` condition and if that `mod_headers.c` module is not available, then the header will be missing from the server's reply. What I would do is make sure the header appears when I try with `wget -S ...` or `curl -D - ...`.

Comment: There is a link to the Mozilla page describing those `Allow-...` headers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS